# how to get div properties text in python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Hope all are doing well. I want to get "data-id" property text. Please anyone help me here to get that. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="_1AtVbE col-12-12">
  <div class="_13oc-S">
    <div data-id="MOBG6WQWRGRRDBH6" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="_2kHMtA" data-tkid="82daf062-714d-464f-b670-ce7681250431.MOBG6WQWRGRRDBH6.SEARCH">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `driver.find_element('css selector', 'div[data-id]').getAttribute('data-id')` -- what does this give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS selector to find div element with data-id attribute

```
driver.find_element('css selector', 'div[data-id]').getAttribute('data-id')
```

Note: since your HTML sample is small this code would work. On a bigger sample, narrow down to the parent of your target div element, or use `find_elements` instead and filter for the element you want.

Reference reading: [All CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
String dataId = driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_2kHMtA']/..")).getAtribute("data-id");
```

Comment: This is giving None. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This is also working but if start a loop on this it is giving for 1 st element text